# Angular UI-bootstrap with Angular JS 1.4.x

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower, bower-install

I am using Angular 1.4.x in my project. I need to use UI-bootstrap. But I see this in the documentation:

•AngularJS (requires AngularJS 1.3.x, tested with 1.3.13). 0.12.0 is the last version of this library that supports AngularJS 1.2.x.

Does this mean I need to downgrade my Angular version to 1.3.x? Or is there a way to resolve this?

bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "boiler",
  "description": "Boiler automation",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.x",
    "angular-mocks": "1.4.x",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-route": "1.4.x",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.x"
  }
}
```

Getting below error on bower install:

```
bower cached        git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#0.13.0
bower validate      0.13.0 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.g
it#~0.13.0
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.2
bower validate      1.4.2 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.
4.x
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.2
bower validate      1.4.2 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=
1.0.8
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.1
bower validate      1.4.1 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4
.1
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.4.2
bower validate      1.4.2 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate
.git#~1.4.x
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.2
bower validate      1.4.2 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4
.2
bower ECONFLICT     Unable to find suitable version for angular

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! boiler@0.0.1 postinstall: `bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the boiler@0.0.1 postinstall script 'bower install'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the boiler package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls boiler
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sreehari.puliyakkot\projects\boiler\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: In my bower config you can see angular-animate is dependent on angular 1.4.x while angular-bootstrap requires angular 1.3.x. How to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

You need version 0.12.1 it's the only one to support angular 1.4:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3633#issuecomment-120455274

Comment: The issue is:bower ECONFLICT     Unable to find suitable version for angular. I tried downgrading ui-bootstrap version to 0.12.1 and get the same error when running bower install

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js